# Access a class method in browser core php

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

In code igniter web application we can can the controller and methods like domain-name/controller/method_name.Is there any way to access core PHP class methods like the same way?

How can i access the method in browser like domain/car/hello

The Car.php file is in the server root xampp/htdocs/Car.php

My class file `Car.php`:-

```
class Car{

public function hello()
{
    echo  'Hello';
}

}
```

Please help.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about routing.

Comment: like we access in codeigniter like localhost/controller/methodname.How can we access in core php

Comment: CodeIgnitor has a *URL router*, which is written in PHP. "Core PHP" just doesn't have any mechanism for this kind of thing.

Comment: Can anyone upvote this question please to remove the negative vote, it was a doubt..am a beginner to core php concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. The browser talks to the server (to PHP) using HTTP. HTTP has absolutely no notion of functions, or even what a programming language is. PHP also has no mechanism to allow anything to directly access/call a function from outside. The only thing that happens is that the web server decides based on the requested URL which PHP script to execute. That's all. Execution will always start on the first line of the script being executed, not directly in a function somewhere.

You can/have to write code which inspects the requested URL or otherwise decides which function to call, and then call it in PHP code.

Comment: The file is in server itself.Suppose we have a php file in server root with the a simple echo "hello" it will work right?If we add a class like i mentioned and i need to access the hello method is it possible, that was my doubt

Comment: The PHP file will be executed and the class will be defined, but unless you write `(new MyClass)->hello()` somewhere nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Php is a **server-side** programming language, you simply cannot execute it in your browser without HTTP Server.

Upd: if you mean how can you run it in xaamp then you should run it. Run this by calling file like simple url page, for example `localhost/Car.php`
Try something like this:

```
<?php

Car $car = new Car();
$car->hello();

class Car{

  public function hello(){
      echo  'Hello';
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually i was asking like , i have a php file like Car.php in my server itself ie in xaamp/htdocs/Car.php.I needd to access the file like normal web applications runs